# DateTime.Now Giving UTC on Linux AWS EC2-Instance

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, amazon-ec2

I am using Dot Net Core 3 and inside my code using this to get the current Date

```
DateTime.Now
```

Trying out with this logs

```
Console.WriteLine("----- Local Time : " + DateTime.Now + "UTC : " + DateTime.UtcNow); 
Giving OutPut Like : ----- Local Time : 01/12/2023 11:27:49 UTC : 01/12/2023 11:27:49
```

But, when i am checking my logs it's prining the UTC time now the Local Time.
Below i have attached the screen showing time on my server . This output i have received using

```
timedatectl
```

[image]

Anyone knows what's going here ?

Comment: Provided code clearly will not result in the provided output. Can you please post all the relevant parts?

Comment: Is the logging framework normalizing to UTC? Why are you expecting local times in the logs?

Comment: @GuruStron                     Console.WriteLine("----- Local Time : " + DateTime.Now + "UTC : " + DateTime.UtcNow); Giving OutPut Like : ----- Local Time : 01/12/2023 12:52:45 UTC : 01/12/2023 12:52:45

Comment: @Rohitesh this also should not produce output on the screenshot.

Comment: @GuruStron this screen shot is taken sometime back and the log is form the current time because of which you are not able to see the correct time . Please see my edits

Comment: So this server is in the UTC "timezone"

Comment: Please post the correct code. The code that you have posted will not produce the output shown the image. Also please do not use images as their URLs degrade over time.